# How to signal end when reading from std input

Tags: node.js

This is the code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin) {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.split('\n');
    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);
    const objCount = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);
    console.log(objCount);
}
```

To start the program from command line I run this:

```
node app.js
```

Then, in the terminal, I enter for example

```
12
13
14
```

I can see that these inputs are added to the variable "inputString". Now I need to end. How can I do it??

I have tried: 1-Having an empty line 2-entering ctrl+D 3-having a new line with a dot 4-entering ctrl-C

But it never goes through the function "end". Only time it does is when I enter ctrl-D. But doing it in the same line as the last parameter, doesn't end it. And if I first go to a new line and then enter ctrl-D then I get this error:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:426
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type undefined
```

Note that Im running oxs.

Comment: Node's standard [`readline` module](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) handles Ctrl+D. Perhaps that is a better choice for your application than reading directly from `stdin`.

Comment: This error occurs when you try to use `process.env.OUTPUT_PATH` in `fs.createWriteStream`, because `process.env.OUTPUT_PATH` is most likely `undefined`. What does `console.log(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH)` output?

Comment: Aha I see. It prints undefined.